# Разбор input file multiple

Tags: jquery

В общем, суть вопроса такова, возможно ли сделать так:

Имеется input file с multiple, когда мы закидываем туда изображения, этот input file в jQuery разбивается на несколько разных input которые мы если что можем удалить.

Поясню как это работает (в теории):

1. Закидываем в input file (multiple) изображения
2. Проходимся циклом по файлам и создаём input с данными этих файлов
3. Вешаем FileReader который отрисовывает нам эти изображения
4. Любое из этих изображений мы можем удалить (следовательно нужно удалять и input)

Так же мы можем догрузить еще изображения и порядок должен остаться. (Аля после всех добавляется новый input)

Возможно ли это всё?

Если нет, то как возможно реализовать данную схему: Закидываем в input > Показ привью > Удаление изображения по этому привью

**Обновление**

Нужно чтобы "ты" мог перетащить файлы в input, и когда файлы появлялись там, если их больше 1, то создавались еще input'ы (Типа, залил 3 файла, создалось 3 input с этими файлами) А если такое нельзя сделать, то нужно просто перетащить файл в Input, при этом его можно было удалить и чтобы он показывался при заливке (не на сервер). Это как предпоказ.

Comment: Могу помочь с решением Вашей задачи, но нужно больше информации

Comment: @Shnur Понять бы что именно нужно D: